# R: Updating SQL table loop using R

Tags: r, rodbc

I am using the RODBC package on R which allows me to connect to SQL using R.

As an example to my problem, I have a table [Sales] within SQL with 3 Columns (Alpha, Beta, BetaDistribution).

1.50,77,x

2.99,53,x

4.50,122,x

Note that the 3rd column (BetaDistribution) is not populated, and this needs to be populated using a Statistical R Function.

---

I have assigned my table to the variable SELECT

select <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select * from dbo.sales')

how to I run a loop to update my sql table so that the BetaDistribution column is updated with the calculated Beta Distribution - pbeta(alpha,beta)

Comment: You listed four columns but referred to Revenue as the third instead of fourth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.  Basically you make a temp table and then update the existing table.  There's a reasonable chance you need to tweak that update statement since I, obviously, can't test it.

```
select$BetaDistribution<-yourfunc(x,y)
sqlSave(dbhandle, select, tablename="dbo.salestemp", rownames=FALSE,varTypes=list(Alpha="decimal(10,10)", Beta="decimal(10,10)", BetaDistribution="decimal(10,10)"))
sqlQuery(dbhandle, "update dbo.sales 
                    set sales.BetaDistribution=salestemp.BetaDistribution 
                    from dbo.sales
                    inner join
                    salestemp
                    on
                    sales.Alpha=salestemp.Alpha and 
                    sales.Beta=salestemp.Beta")
sqlQuery(dbhandle, "drop table salestemp")
```

Comment: Thanks...however I just simplified the problem so I could describe in an easier way. Maybe not the cleverest thing to do.

Comment: I need to take a variables from sql and apply a beta distribution within R...and I would like to update the SQL table with a results of the beta distribution for each row within the SQL table.

Comment: You should update your question to specify you want to update your sql table with the result of an arbitrary R function instead of multiplication.  Also include what DB you're using as the answer will depend on that.

Comment: @SIMONHART does this work for your needs?  If so, would you consider accepting the answer.

Comment: It does...thank you very much for your assitance. Has it been accepted?

Comment: @SIMONHART not yet.  You have to click the checkmark.